# Multilevel CFA in R (lavaan); Error: No variance within some clusters

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I am running a multilevel CFA in R package lavaan (following the process by Dyer, Hanges, & Hall, 2005). I was able to run an individual-level CFA, and examine both the within group covariance matrix and between group covariance matrix CFAs (as well as rwg and ICCs for aggregation) without problem, and the fit statistics looked good. However, when I ran the multilevel CFA, I receive the error: "Level-1 variable “x1.1” has no variance within some clusters. The cluster ids with zero within variance are: GR1 GR30" I receive this error multiple times for most items across numerous groups because the people in those groups had the same response for that item. Thus, the model did not converge.

I am new to multilevel CFA and am still wrapping my head around the underlying equations and theory, but I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong, if there is something I can do to remedy this problem, or can I not run a multilevel CFA if I have groups with no within group variance for some items?

For background, I am working with a model where 3 individual-level factors are hypothesized to operate similarly (as 3 factors) at the group level. My code is fairly basic:

```
mCFAfact <- '
level: 1
  F1i =~ x1.1 + x1.2 + x1.3 + x1.4 
  F2i =~ b1.1 + b1.2 + b1.3
  F3i =~ s1.1 + s1.2 + s1.3 + s1.4 + s1.5
level: 2
  F1g =~ x1.1 + x1.2 + x1.3 + x1.4 
  F2g =~ b1.1 + b1.2 + b1.3
  F2g =~ s1.1 + s1.2 + s1.3 + s1.4 + s1.5
'

mCFAresult <- cfa(mCFAfact, data = datCFA1, cluster = 'group')
summary(mCFAresult, fit.measures = T, standardized = T)
```

I tried making a sample dataset for reproducibility, but I had trouble replicating my errors without causing new errors, and I cannot share the data I am working with. However, I'm hoping maybe I made a simple mistake or there's something I can do with my data to proceed with a multilevel CFA? TIA!